# Introduction of new tags to achieve consistency throughout SE sites

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

To achieve consistency for tagging questions about Dynamics CRM throughout the SE network, I would like to know if it's possible to create the tags listed under [***dynamics-crm****](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm*).

Questions on serverfault.com about this topic are currently tagged with [microsoft-crm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-crm) or [mscrm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mscrm)

Questions, which are currently tagged with [microsoft-crm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-crm) or [mscrm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mscrm), should then be retagged to *dynamics-crm*.

It the tags will be created, I can retag them to the appropriate version (if the question is version specific).

Comment: If this went trough then the tags could be synonymed.

Comment: Properly the parent tag should be [tag:microsoft-dynamics-crm]; could easily synonym all the variants to that.

Comment: Merged all mscrm with microsoft-crm and added synonym for Microsoft-Dynamics-CRM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the name of the actual software is Microsoft Dynamics CRM, I would argue that people are more likely to refer to it as Microsoft CRM, rather than Dynamics CRM. As there are currently no questions tagged with dynamics-crm it would seem a little abritary to change all the microsoft-crm ones. That said Stackoverflow does seem to only have tags relating to dynamics-crm.

Comment: We can just synonym them all any way... No biggie.

Comment: Indeed, I would suggest that microsoft-crm or microsoft-dynamics-crm is the primary tag though